# Is there a way to check for a CustomAction failing without aborting installation?

Tags: wix, custom-action

If I have the following CustomAction the installation will abort if DoTask fails.

```
<CustomAction Id='DoTask'
              Execute='deferred'
              FileKey="MyExe"
              Return='check' />
```

If I set `Return` to `ignore`, installation will carry on if it fails, but I'll get no indication that it has.

Is there a way of setting a `Property` if the `CustomAction` fails? I would like to continue installation, but display a message to the user afterwards if the tool has failed.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done only from custom actions which can set installer properties: Win32 DLL, VBScript, WiX toolset action, etc.

For custom actions you cannot handle the return value. The best you can do is save the information somewhere from inside the custom action (for example, a property) and make the installer read it after the custom action runs.